# MVC ASP.NET - the link on my email does not work - I need to refresh the screen

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When I create a new contract I send an email to all interested parties. However the link in my email will open a new screen, but only when I press F5 do I see the page login page, and then the page I am navigating to. How do I fix this?
A typical link is

http://localhost:3838/Contract/Details/14

My Controller Action is

```
   /****************
     * DETAILS
     ************* */
    [Authorize(Roles = "Reader,Inputter,Administrator")]
    public ViewResult Details(int contractId)
    {
        return View(new ContractViewModel(contractId));
    }
```

Comment: We need to know what your controller and action method are doing. The url doesn't tell us enough information.

Comment: I have added the info you request. This is in the Contract Controller.

Comment: My first intuition is something with AuthorizeAttribute since it is most likely preventing a user from seeing something, but then I would expect some kind of exception, not a blank screen. Likely you will need to debug this yourself, and determine what is happening.

Comment: It seems to happen when I have a number of tabs already open in IE

Comment: debug the shit out of this then provide some more information. There's just not enough to go on as it is. Ps, if the roles were the issue you would be redirected to your login page

Comment: OK, well I need some advice then on what kind of debugging I need to do to get better information. What would you do?

Comment: When I press F5 I get the login page, and that is fine by me. I have edited my original message to make that clear.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you browser is caching the website while you are testing?

It sounds like you are using a new version of IE so:

```
Go to Tools --> Internet Options --> Temporary Internet Files --> Settings. 

Set it to check for newer versions of stored pages "Every visit to the page".
```

Or if you prefer a code fix you could use a NoCacheAttribute on your controller, although this is not recommended because you probably will want caching eventually:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public sealed class NoCacheAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}

[NoCache]
public class YourController : Controller 
{
    ...
}
```